# Monad Transformer stacks with MaybeT and RandT

Tags: haskell, random, monad-transformers, option-type

I'm trying to learn how Monad Transformers work by re-factoring something I wrote when I first learned Haskell. It has quite a few components that could be replaced with a (rather large) stack of Monad Transformers.

I started by writing a type alias for my stack:

```
type SolverT a = MaybeT
                    (WriterT Leaderboard
                        (ReaderT Problem
                            (StateT SolutionState
                                (Rand StdGen)))) a
```

A quick rundown:

- `Rand` threads through a `StdGen` used in various random operations
- `StateT` carries the state of the solution as it gets progressively evaluated
- `ReaderT` has a fixed state Problem space being solved
- `WriterT` has a leaderboard constantly updated by the solution with the best version(s) so far
- `MaybeT` is needed because both the problem and solution state use `lookup` from `Data.Map`, and any error in how they are configured would lead to a `Nothing`

In the original version a `Nothing` "never" happened because I only used a `Map` for efficient lookups for known key/value pairs (I suppose I could refactor to use an array). In the original I got around the `Maybe` problem by making a liberal use of `fromJust`.

From what I understand having `MaybeT` at the top means that in the event of a `Nothing` in any `SolverT a` I don't lose any of the information in my other transformers, as they are unwrapped from outside-in.

**Side question**

[EDIT: This was a problem because I didn't use a sandbox, so I had old/conflicting versions of libraries causing an issue]

When I first wrote the stack I had `RandT` at the top. I decided to avoid using `lift` everywhere or writing my own instance declarations for all the other transformers for `RandT`. So I moved it to the bottom.

I did try writing an instance declaration for `MonadReader` and this was about as much as I could get to compile:

```
instance (MonadReader r m,RandomGen g) => MonadReader r (RandT g m) where
    ask = undefined
    local = undefined
    reader = undefined
```

I just couldn't get any combination of `lift`, `liftRand` and `liftRandT` to work in the definition. It's not particularly important but I am curious about what a valid definition might be?

**Problem 1**

[EDIT: This was a problem because I didn't use a sandbox, so I had old/conflicting versions of libraries causing an issue]

Even though MonadRandom has instances of everything (except MaybeT) I still had to write my own instance declarations for each Transformer:

```
instance (MonadRandom m) => MonadRandom (MaybeT m) where
    getRandom = lift getRandom
    getRandomR = lift . getRandomR
    getRandoms = lift getRandoms
    getRandomRs = lift . getRandomRs
```

I did this for `WriterT`, `ReaderT` and `StateT` by copying the instances from the [MonadRandom source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.3.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Random.html#RandT). Note: for `StateT` and `WriterT` they do use qualified imports but not for Reader. If I didn't write my own declarations I got errors like this:

```
No instance for (MonadRandom (ReaderT Problem (StateT SolutionState (Rand StdGen))))
  arising from a use of `getRandomR'
```

I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

**Problem 2**

With the above in hand, I re-wrote one of my functions:

```
randomCity :: SolverT City
randomCity = do
    cits <- asks getCities
    x <- getRandomR (0,M.size cits -1)
    --rc <- M.lookup x cits
    return undefined --rc
```

The above compiles and I think is how transformers are suppose to be used. In-spite of the tedium of having to write repetitive transformer instances, this is pretty handy. You'll notice that in the above I've commented out two parts. If I remove the comments I get:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe'
              with `MaybeT
                      (WriterT
                         Leaderboard
                         (ReaderT Problem (StateT SolutionState (Rand StdGen))))'
Expected type: MaybeT
                 (WriterT
                    Leaderboard (ReaderT Problem (StateT SolutionState (Rand StdGen))))
                 City
  Actual type: Maybe City
```

At first I thought the problem was about the types of Monads that they are. All of the other Monads in the stack have a constructor for `(\s -> (a,s))` while Maybe has `Just a | Nothing`. But that shouldn't make a difference, the type for `ask` should return `Reader r a`, while `lookup k m` should give a type `Maybe a`.

I thought I would check my assumption, so I went into GHCI and checked these types:

```
> :t ask
ask :: MonadReader r m => m r
> :t (Just 5)
(Just 5) :: Num a => Maybe a
> :t MaybeT 5
MaybeT 5 :: Num (m (Maybe a)) => MaybeT m a
```

I can see that all of my other transformers define a type class that can be lifted through a transformer. `MaybeT` doesn't seem to have a `MonadMaybe` typeclass.

I know that with `lift` I can lift something from my transformer stack into `MaybeT`, so that I can end up with `MaybeT m a`. But if I end up with `Maybe a` I assumed that I could bind it in a `do` block with `<-`.

**Problem 3**

I actually have one more thing to add to my stack and I'm not sure where it should go. The `Solver` operates on a fixed number of cycles. I need to keep track of the current cycle vs the max cycle. I could add the cycle count to the solution state, but I'm wondering if there is an additional transformer I could add.

Further to that, how many transformers is too many? I know this is incredibly subjective but surely there is a performance cost on these transformers? I imagine some amount of fusion can optimise this at compile time so maybe the performance cost is minimal?

Comment: This really seems like it should be three seperate questions. 1) This works for me: `let x :: ReaderT Problem (StateT SolutionState (Rand StdGen)) Int; x = getRandomR (1,2)`. What version of each package are you using? 2) Maybe is not MaybeT. You simply cannot have `a <- lookup b c` unless your monad is *exactly* Maybe. Instead do `a <- MaybeT $ return $ lookup b c`. `embed = MaybeT . return` is useful. 3) What I do is have a type like `type MyMonad m = (MonadState T m, MonadReader Q m, MonadRandom m)`, etc. Then later I decide which "order" of transformers I want.

Comment: And lastly, all of these monad transformers are defined using `newtype` so their runtime cost is essentially the same as "manually" manipulating your effects as functions. Essentially the only "optimization" you can do is decide you don't need a particular effect. The only thing I would do is replace ReaderT/WriterT/StateT with RWST, but since they are isomorphic, it won't affect your performance - it is just style.

Comment: Seemed a bit weird to ask 3 questions about the same small code snippet. FYI - you've answered all of my questions in 2 short comments. Would be happy to accept as an answer... (1) You were right, the MonadRandom instances did work, I just had old/conflicting versions. Should have used a sandbox. (2) I think I understand. Is this because `Maybe` isn't `MaybeT Identity` like other types are? (3) RWS sounds awesome. But I'm not sure I follow how your proposed type alias works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 1

Can't reproduce. There are already these instances for `RandT`.

### Problem 2

`lookup` returns `Maybe`, but you have a stack based on `MaybeT`. The reason why there is no `MonadMaybe` is that the corresponding type class is `MonadPlus` (or more general `Alternative`) - `pure`/`return` correspond to `Just` and `empty`/`mzero` correspond to `Nothing`. I'd suggest to create a helper

```
lookupA :: (Alternative f, Ord k) => k -> M.Map k v -> f v
lookupA k = maybe empty pure . M.lookup k
```

and then you can call `lookupA` wherever you need in your monad stack

As mentioned in the comments, I'd strongly suggest to use `RWST`, as it's exactly what fits your case, and it's much easier to work with than the stack of StateT/ReaderT/WriterT.

Also think about the difference between

```
type Solver a = RWST Problem Leaderboard SolutionState (MaybeT (Rand StdGen)) a
```

and

```
type Solver a = MaybeT (RWST Problem Leaderboard SolutionState (Rand StdGen)) a
```

The difference is what happens in the case of a failure. The former stack doesn't return anything, while the latter allows you to retrieve the state and the `Leaderboard` computed so far.

### Problem 3

The easiest way is to add it into the state part. I'd just include it into `SolutionState`.

### Sample code

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad.Random.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.RWS
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Monoid
import System.Random

-- Dummy data types to satisfy the compiler
data Problem = Problem
data Leaderboard = Leaderboard
data SolutionState = SolutionState
data City = City

instance Monoid Leaderboard where
  mempty = Leaderboard
  mappend _ _ = Leaderboard

-- dummy function
getCities :: Problem -> M.Map Int City
getCities _ = M.singleton 0 City

-- the actual sample code

type Solver a = RWST Problem Leaderboard SolutionState (MaybeT (Rand StdGen)) a

lookupA :: (Alternative f, Ord k) => k -> M.Map k v -> f v
lookupA k = maybe empty pure . M.lookup k

randomCity :: Solver City
randomCity = do
    cits <- asks getCities
    x <- getRandomR (0, M.size cits - 1)
    lookupA x cits
```